# import picasa google album by using phoca gallery component of joomla 3

Tags: image, joomla, gallery, picasa

I am trying to fetch my picasa album photos in my website.
I am using joomla 3 and phoca gallery component.
As per documentation available in google, I have provided correct userid, album name and auth key. But when I am trying to import photo by clicking Picasa(google+) Import, it is showing

```
Error

Save failed with the following error: Picasa Album not found. Check the Album field.
```

Could you please help me how to integrate this? or could you please let me know any sample data to test this whether my component is bug-free or not.

Comment: Anybody is there? Please help me.

Comment: same problem here... according to http://www.phoca.cz/documents/2-phoca-gallery-component/321-displaying-google-picasa-web-albums-or-google-plus-web-albums you have to switch to picasaweb.google.com to get the right "old" ids... but it won't work if you're not the album owner

Comment: I got the expected result after installing in server. While it was in my localhost, it is not working. Thanks for your suggestion, let me check this in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

i finally got this to work... when you're on a Google+ album (even if you're note the owner), add this: `?banner=pwa` at the end of the url.

You should get an popup like this:

[image: Google+ to picasa switcher]

(sorry it's french but english version should be similar)

after clicking on "Ici" (or "Here"), the url is changed to something like this: `https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/sredir?uname=897987465465416313213&target=ALBUM&id=7978987984654635136&authkey=z78bv9zar7vavbarbarb&noredirect=1`

where :

897987465465416313213 is Picasa (Google+) User
7978987984654635136 is Picasa (Google+) Album
et z78bv9zar7vavbarbarb is the Authentication key

(i faked the ids and key).

Enjoy.